# Show fields based on $localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-storage

I want to show fields inn the page based on $localStorage value.

If I have the following :

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li> List 1 </li>
        <li> List 2 </li>
        <li> List 3 </li>
        <li> List 4 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I want to show the `List 3` and `List 4` only if the value of $localStorage is not `0`.

How do i do that ?

Comment: Please show us your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value from the $localStorage and set to scope variable and check for the variable using ng-if

```
$scope.condvalue = localStorage.getItem("yourItem");
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li> List 1 </li>
        <li> List 2 </li>
        <li ng-if="condvalue!=0"> List 3 </li>
        <li ng-if="condvalue!=0">  List 4 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly you need to inject  $window in your controller to use localStorage

```
//here you need to set the varialble which is ListisnotZero  
  $window.localStorage.setItem("ListisnotZero", ListisnotZero);
//then get it from the localstorage
    $scope.ListisnotZero= $window.localStorage.getItem("ListisnotZero");


     //   in html
         <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li> List 1 </li>
        <li> List 2 </li>
        <li ng-if="ListisnotZero != 0 "> List 3 </li>
        <li ng-if="ListisnotZero != 0 "> List 4 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think they're talking about [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) (I didn't downvoted BTW)

Comment: @AlonEitan LOL thanks for letting me know idk now in stack even sharing knowledge is becoming dangerous

Comment: Don't worry - I've fixed that :)

Comment: @AlonEitan thnk u bud :P